# Shouldn't the /token endpoint (OAuth2) of FastAPI Services always be ratelimited

Tags: fastapi

The official FastAPI Tutorial (which I regard as "best practice") contains an [Applications Note for OAuth2](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/). It describes that a "/token" Endpoint has to be created that verifys a username/password and returns a token.

As recommended there, the bcrypt hash verification algorithm shall be used which is, by design, very slow. This means an attacker could start a lot of requests to the /token endpoint with a known username and an invalid hash and thus provoke a lot of computational intensive bcrypt operations (~500ms per hash verification on my core-i7 laptop).

This could easily result in DoS, right?
If so one should always add a rate limiter to the /token endpoint as "best practice", right?
Or did I miss sth.?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to rate limit this endpoint